# Как поместить pdf файл на форму C# ?

Tags: c#, pdf

Необходимо импортировать pdf-файл на форму. 
Как это реализовать? С помощью каких библиотек, если они нужны?

Comment: эммм..на какую форму?

Answer (score 4):

Если вы имеете ввиду `WinForms`, то `AcroPdf Active X control`

Почитайте:

- [PDF component in WinForms using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/290805/PDF-component-in-WinForms-using-Csharp)
- [using Adobe Reader ActiveX Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004423/using-adobe-reader-activex-control)

Comment: Спасибо. Правда, скачать не удаётся. Скачал Axinterop.AcroPDFLib, правда для VS 2008. Под VS 2012 не катит(
Где нормальную скачать можно?

Answer (score 1):

Если ещё актуально, я использавал **Apitron.PDF.Controls for .NET** 
Просто бросил на форму, добавил события для навигации и поиска, получилось что-то вроде адобовского акробат вьювера. Удобно. (нашей конторе контролы бесплатно т.к. были лицензии на другие продукты куплены). 
Но можно просто в картинку сконвертировать при помощи **Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer for .NET**, в сэмплах есть реализованый простой WinForms вьювер, если что можно допилить.

```
using Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer;
using Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer.Configuration;
...
// открыли поток PDF файла на чтение
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\Documents\testfile.pdf", FileMode.Open))
{
    // передали поток документу
    Document document = new Document(fs);

    // постранично сохраняем в картинки
    for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        Page currentPage = document.Pages[i];

        // можно поменять настройки DPI, размер, формат сохраняемого изображения
        using (Bitmap bitmap = currentPage.Render((int)currentPage.Width, (int)currentPage.Height, new RenderingSettings()))
        {
            bitmap.Save(string.Format("{0}.bmp", i), ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }
    }
}
```